# Can't execute 64bit libs on Raspi PI4

Tags: java, dynamic-linking, raspberry-pi4

I have activate 64bit kernel on my Raspi4:

```
pi@pc:~ $ uname -a
Linux pc 5.10.63-v8+ #1496 SMP PREEMPT Wed Dec 1 15:59:46 GMT 2021 aarch64 GNU/Linux
pi@pc:~ $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
Codename:   buster
```

I'm trying to run latest java version (original Oracle Arm 64-bit version) on my machine. Though, running the binary results in a file not found error despite the file being present and executable:

```
pi@pc:~ $ /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17.0.1/bin/java -version
bash: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17.0.1/bin/java: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
pi@pc:~ $ ls -la /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17.0.1/bin/java
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 70856 Sep 27 19:45 /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17.0.1/bin/java
```

Only ldd command giving an indication, program not dynamically linked:

```
pi@pc:~ $ ldd /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17.0.1/bin/java
    das Programm ist nicht dynamisch gelinkt
```

file command showing the following output:

```
pi@pc:~ $ file /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17.0.1/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17.0.1/bin/java: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1, for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, not stripped
pi@pc:~ $ file /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8-oracle-ARM32/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8-oracle-ARM32/bin/java: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 2.6.26, BuildID[sha1]=c61f921ef55f64705b9f360005fb2b77e4a81ac3, not stripped
```

I'm not an expert in C/C++ programming. Is there any way, the executable can be run on my Raspi?

Comment: What is the output of `file /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17.0.1/bin/java`?

Comment: @MBizm Please do not post code or console output to comments. Edit your question instead and add the output formatted as code there.

Comment: I have added file output above. It also contains the ouput for JDK1.8 version (original Oracle 32bit) for comparison.

Comment: Does `/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1` exist?

Comment: You are right, it is missing. What is the best way for adding it? Any rerefence, how best to install/compile it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using a custom Raspberry image for 64-bit. I also ran into this problem. I'm using Raspios: https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_lite_arm64/images/

With the next image, you can install java 17 on the PI. So far no problems with running Java jar's.

[image: Install java 17 on Raspberry PI4]

Comment: Thanks @Stijn-leenknegt! Reference to alternative Raspi images as helpful. Java 64bit version runs perfectly on 64bit Bullseye Raspbion distro. And it was worth the effort from performance and UI perspective.

Answer (score 0):

One defintely "can't execute 64bit libs" in `/usr/lib` - as the path may suggest.

I'd assume this should rather be `/usr/lib64` for `ARM64` architecture.